# R: as_tbl_time Error: Specified `index` is not time based

Tags: r

This is my very first post and I am completely new to R (RGui), I deeply apologise if I am writing in the wrong place, section or even on the wrong website. I hope it's not!

I spend a few days trying to work out a way to solve the issue I've got, but I can't find a solution.

I am trying to use the `anomalize` package.
This requires to transform the data in `tibble time`.

After I've imported my data (.CSV), I have been able to transform them into tibble (`tbl_df`) but, if I try to convert them into `tbl_time` I get this message:

> Error: Specified index is not time based

I have tried to adjust the .CSV format (not sure if that is needed) changing the date format and the labels, but still... doesn't work!

I will paste what I've got, I am sure some of you will be able to help me. Thanks a lot!

This is part of the original dataset, as simple as monthly acquisition datapoints (`gwt`) and the acquisition date next to it (`date`)

```
              date gwt
1 01/02/2003 01:21:18 0.41
2 01/03/2003 01:21:18 0.35
3 01/04/2003 01:21:18 0.22
4 01/05/2003 01:21:18 0.03
5 01/06/2003 01:21:18 -0.05
6 01/07/2003 01:21:18 -0.09
7 01/08/2003 01:21:18 -0.10
8 01/09/2003 01:21:18 -0.02
9 01/10/2003 01:21:18 0.04
10 01/11/2003 01:21:18 0.11
11 01/12/2003 01:21:18 0.08
12 01/01/2004 01:21:18 0.00
13 01/02/2004 01:21:18 -0.19
14 01/03/2004 01:21:18 -0.34
15 01/04/2004 01:21:18 -0.46
16 01/05/2004 01:21:18 -0.59
17 01/06/2004 01:21:18 -0.63
```

This is the `tbl_df` I've been able to obtain:

```
A tibble: 46 x 2
date gwt

    1 01/02/2003 01:21:18 0.41
    2 01/03/2003 01:21:18 0.35
    3 01/04/2003 01:21:18 0.22
    4 01/05/2003 01:21:18 0.03
    5 01/06/2003 01:21:18 -0.05
    6 01/07/2003 01:21:18 -0.09
    7 01/08/2003 01:21:18 -0.1
    8 01/09/2003 01:21:18 -0.02
    9 01/10/2003 01:21:18 0.04
    10 01/11/2003 01:21:18 0.11

... with 36 more rows
```

and this is the message I get when I try to get the `tbl_time` (as mentioned above):

```
t2 <- as_tbl_time(t1, date)
Error: Specified 'index' is not time based
```

P.S. I've tried to change the format, removing the time and leaving the date only, but it doesn't make any difference.

Is anyone able to help? I'd much appreciate it

Sorry again for the long post apologise in advance for any mistake.

Kind regards,

Simone

Answer (score 0):

I know how frustrating it can be at first to work with correct column formats.

I would suggest checking whether your columns are in a correct format after you read your `.csv` file and transform it into `tbl_df`. I suspect your `date` column is of `character` type. So, the easiest way is to use `transmute` function from `dplyr` to re-format your `date` column:

```
tbl <- tbl_df %>% 
  transmute(date = as.POSIXct(strptime(date,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")),
            gwt = gwt)
```

Your `tbl` should look like this:

```
> tbl
# A tibble: 17 x 2
   date                  gwt
   <dttm>              <dbl>
 1 2003-02-01 01:21:18  0.41
 2 2003-03-01 01:21:18  0.35
 3 2003-04-01 01:21:18  0.22
 4 2003-05-01 01:21:18  0.03
 5 2003-06-01 01:21:18 -0.05
 6 2003-07-01 01:21:18 -0.09
 7 2003-08-01 01:21:18 -0.1 
 8 2003-09-01 01:21:18 -0.02
 9 2003-10-01 01:21:18  0.04
10 2003-11-01 01:21:18  0.11
11 2003-12-01 01:21:18  0.08
12 2004-01-01 01:21:18  0   
13 2004-02-01 01:21:18 -0.19
14 2004-03-01 01:21:18 -0.34
15 2004-04-01 01:21:18 -0.46
16 2004-05-01 01:21:18 -0.59
17 2004-06-01 01:21:18 -0.63
```

Pay attention to the type of the `date` column - it is now `dttm`.

Now you can easily convert `tbl` into a time-aware `tbl`:

```
tbl.t <- tbl_time(tbl,index = date)
```

Here is the result:

```
> tbl.t
# A time tibble: 17 x 2
# Index: date
   date                  gwt
   <dttm>              <dbl>
 1 2003-02-01 01:21:18  0.41
 2 2003-03-01 01:21:18  0.35
 3 2003-04-01 01:21:18  0.22
 4 2003-05-01 01:21:18  0.03
 5 2003-06-01 01:21:18 -0.05
 6 2003-07-01 01:21:18 -0.09
 7 2003-08-01 01:21:18 -0.1 
 8 2003-09-01 01:21:18 -0.02
 9 2003-10-01 01:21:18  0.04
10 2003-11-01 01:21:18  0.11
11 2003-12-01 01:21:18  0.08
12 2004-01-01 01:21:18  0   
13 2004-02-01 01:21:18 -0.19
14 2004-03-01 01:21:18 -0.34
15 2004-04-01 01:21:18 -0.46
16 2004-05-01 01:21:18 -0.59
17 2004-06-01 01:21:18 -0.63
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved it in another way just because I received a quicker reply in another forum but I much appreciated your timely help. Thanks once again